# configuration mode on canvas

Tags: info-visualisation, data, toggle, connection, infographic

I am creating a switch visualisation system for IT managers, one of the features I am adding is creating a new authorization relationship between one switch to another. so that one switch is the server (gives approvals) and all of the other switch are his clients. and now for the question: I need to create a mode where the user can configure the client - server relationships. I thought about changing the interface colors, like in adrenaline mode in shooter games (Call of duty for example), [image: another option is to do it like drop box is doing it] do you guys have any suggestions how can I show the user that he is in a configuration mode? be creative :)+

Answer (score 1):

Department stores change floor and fixing colours to subtly change the mood of a shopper, for example when transitioning from clothing to a food department. So I agree in principal, executed with the right subtleties your concept could work. Without seeing the project, maybe keep core background colours so as not to completely throw the users eye… but change flashes of the surrounding or complimentary colours?

Comment: Hi
the color concept as effecting the mood is interesting, hoever,
any ideas how to do it without using colors, I mean, another ideas?

Comment: Personally, I think colour is the way forward, otherwise perhaps use some kind of sticky bar or banner across the top (or somehere obvious on the interface) with a notification in it?

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not sure I understand the question.*

## Self-evident state

When an admin signs into a system, the presence/availability of the admin settings themselves clarifies the authorization. If the user is looking at client/server settings, there should be no doubt about the current mode.

Does the user need to be reminded of this state so they remember to exit? Could this configuration be wrapped in a workflow that guides the user to a completion step?

## Additional controls area

To emphasize that the active user is in Admin mode, consider what is different about this environment. Are there global tools that aren't otherwise available? A CMS website in admin mode comes to mind. Squarespace, Wordpress, and Drupal all introduce a new toolbar over the existing site interface.

[image: Squarespace site in admin mode.]